# Tool to scan for WLANs

Tags: networking

The wifi radio space is crowded, so scanning which channel(s) are the least crowded is advisable.

What is a good tool to do this task? It should

- List all nearby AP's with radio channel, SSID, MAC Adress and encryption type
- Scan both 2.4Ghz (802.11b/g/n) and 5Ghz(802.11a/n) frequencies
- Be compatible with Windows 7 and 8
- Be free or very cheap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WifiInfoView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html) is another usual wifi scanner on Windows:

It does

- List all nearby AP's with radio channel, SSID, MAC Adress and encryption type
- Scan both 2.4Ghz (802.11b/g/n) and 5Ghz(802.11a/n) frequencies
- Be compatible with  Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows Server 2008. Both 32-bit and x64 systems are supported.
- Be free (and portable)

And it's NirSoft quality.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[inSSIDer](http://www.inssider.com/) is a wifi scanner on Windows and Mac.

It does

- Cost $20
- List all nearby AP's with radio channel, SSID, MAC Adress and encryption type
- Scan both 2.4Ghz (802.11b/g/n) and 5Ghz(802.11a/n) frequencies
- Be compatible with Windows 7, Windows 8, and Mac.

[image]

[image]